# Hibernate aren't creating my tables in database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, maven

In the current state my Spring/Maven project, I have two entity classes which should br created in my postgresql database. The Hibernate configuration class is this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:database.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "spring.webapp.persistence" })
public class HibernateConfig {

   @Autowired
   private Environment env;

   @Bean
   public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
      LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
      sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
      sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "spring.webapp.persistence.model" });
      sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

      return sessionFactory;
   }

   @Bean
   public DataSource restDataSource() {
      BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
      dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassname"));
      dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
      dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
      dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass"));

      return dataSource;
   }

   @Bean
   @Autowired
   public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
      HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
      txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

      return txManager;
   }

   @Bean
   public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
      return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
   }

   Properties hibernateProperties() {
      return new Properties() {
         /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        {
            setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
            setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
            setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");
         }
      };
   }
}
```

my file database.properties is:

```
jdbc.driverClassname=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/maven_test?charSet=LATIN1
jdbc.user=klebermo
jdbc.pass=123
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
```

I add the postgresql jdbc driver via pom.xml, with this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>9.1-901.jdbc3</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Anyone can see what's wrong with this setting? Because none table is being created in the database when I run the application.

Comment: post your Entity classes (well at least one of them)

Comment: you can see all of them here: https://github.com/klebermo/maven_example/tree/master/src/main/java/spring/example/persistence/model

Comment: any error you can see in logs

Comment: No, none error is displayed in the log. See here: http://www.klebermota.eti.br/wp-content/tomcat.txt

Comment: what is name of table?

Comment: Ok, I find the problem now. Happens I had the wrong path in the annotation @ComponentScan. I fix and now the tables were created normally. thank you by your suggestions, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I find the problem now. Happens I had the wrong path in the annotation @ComponentScan. I fix and now the tables were created normally. thank you by your suggestions, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update** instead create-drop
update is used for create new table and also update old table(if changes are there)

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Yes, I test with update (it was my first try, actually), but don't work too.

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
   <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
   <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
  </dependency> try this.

Comment: I try this too. See the output from console here: http://www.klebermota.eti.br/wp-content/tomcat.txt

Comment: what is name of table?